# DataGrid ListCollectionView sorting

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a view model that exposes an ListCollectionView and data grid that is bound to it. For some reason when swapping the ListCollectionView and creating a new one from the source collection the sorting is lost for the new items that are added to the source collection.

The source collection is an ObservableCollection.
The sorting is correct for the items that already exist in source collection on ListCollectionView creation.
I dont use GetDefaultView but instead create ListCollectionView myself whenever required.
When adding new items to the source collection no sorting is done and items appear at the end of the list.
I raise INotifyPropertyChanged when swapping ListCollectionView.

Anyone knows why i get such behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in however you create your listcollectionview. ( You should have posted that code. )

I put some experimental code together, which works as I expected. I just use a listbox but this will make no difference.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Command="{Binding AddPersonCommand}" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
             >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Viewmodel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private RelayCommand addPersonCommand;
    public RelayCommand AddPersonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return addPersonCommand
            ?? (addPersonCommand = new RelayCommand(
              () =>
             {
                 People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Adam", LastName = "Barlow" });
             }
             ));
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Person> people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get { return people; }
        set { people = value; }
    }


    public ListCollectionView LCV { get; set; }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        LCV = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(People);
        LCV.SortDescriptions.Add(
            new SortDescription("LastName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Chesney", LastName = "Brown" });
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Gary", LastName = "Windass" });
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Liz", LastName = "McDonald" });
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Carla", LastName = "Connor" });
    }
}
```

When I click the button it adds Ken Barlow to the observablecollection and it appears top of the listbox.

I also tried binding to LCV:

And instantiating that passing people in via the ctor.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private RelayCommand addPersonCommand;
    public RelayCommand AddPersonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return addPersonCommand
            ?? (addPersonCommand = new RelayCommand(
              () =>
              {
                  Person person = new Person { FirstName = "Adam", LastName = "Barlow" };
                  People.Add(person);
              }
             ));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get { return people; }
        set { people = value; }
    }

    public ListCollectionView LCV { get; set; }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Chesney", LastName = "Brown" });
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Gary", LastName = "Windass" });
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Liz", LastName = "McDonald" });
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Carla", LastName = "Connor" });
        LCV = new ListCollectionView(People);
        LCV.SortDescriptions.Add(
            new SortDescription("LastName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    }
}
```

This also works.

Comment: So i created a small example to test and indeed its easy to replicate the behavior.
Basically doing this   var collectionView = new ListCollectionView(source); and then swapping the view will not work BUT doing this     var collectionView =CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(source); will work.
I can post the source if required.

Comment: Or bind to the listcollectionview.

Comment: So to be more precise its the data grid sorting that is lost, if you click on header and sort by some of the members then next added items are sorted correctly.
So basically after view collection is reset the default sorting is gone even if you add it when creating collection view.